# Read from unknown json structure - beginner

Tags: c#, jsonconvert

I have a JSON string, and I need to extract values from it- for example I need to get the value for `ID` and `Name`.

```
string someJson = @"[ {'ID': '12'} , { 'Name' : 'JAMES'} ]";
```

Note: I don't have a model created for this `JSON`.

My code:

```
string someJson = @"[ {'ID': '12'} , { 'Name' : 'JAMES'} ]"; 

List<object> json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>(someJson);


Console.WriteLine("json count ", json[0]["ID"]);
```

The console.write doesn't print `ID` or can print `Name`. How can I solve this ?
I hope I explained the question well, Sorry I am a newbie.

Comment: Does that even compile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserialize JSON into C# dynamic object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object)

Comment: Without `["ID"]` it does compile.

Comment: @Illep you _should_ create a model for this.  Strongly C# is a strongly typed language, play to its strengths!  Also, your Json seems very wrong to me.  Its an array of objects but all the objects are different?  Why would it be structured like that?  Is this something you control?

Comment: @maccettura I do not agree at all, using lists and dictionaries is very generic (obviously) and flexible, and you can handle unkown or not fixed json. Javascript is NOT strongly typed but that is where it comes from and often some guy will just add a field to that JSON and that should not break your server. (-J-ava-S-cript-O-bject-Notation-)

Comment: @Gene that is just one possible solution of the question

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("json count ", json[0]["ID"]);` this will never print anything else then 'json count '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse to a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>`

Check this [example](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm) from JSON.NET.

Your example would look like this:

```
string someJson = @"[ {'ID': '12'} , { 'Name' : 'JAMES'} ]";
List<Dictionary<string, string>> student = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>(someJson );
object val = student[0]["ID"];
Console.WriteLine($"json count {val.ToString()}");
```

Comment: It doesn't print the value.

Comment: ok now it does (checked), the output line from your question is wrong in the first place (seems updated, or I mistyped)

Comment: @MartinMeeser So absolutely no mention of the JSON structure's weirdness?  Just solving the perceived problem is not the most helpful, sometimes there are bigger problems at play.  This is likely an XY Problem, especially if the OP controls the Json

Comment: @maccettura I find having the jsons flexible is great and very much looking at the big picture, but hey, that discussion just belongs to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/, here at SO: concrete question, concrete answer, thats 100% ok

Answer (score 1):

You could use deserialize into a JArray

```
    string someJson = @"[ {'ID': '12'} , { 'Name' : 'JAMES'} ]"; 

    var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(someJson);

    Console.WriteLine("json count " + json[0]["ID"]);
```

Comment: I think there are bigger concerns here, that Json structure is problematic.  We should get to the bottom of that first

Comment: @maccettura what do you mean ?

Comment: @Illep your json is an array of objects but each object is different. This is normally not what you’d expect or do

Comment: @Illep do you control the json?

Comment: Depends if he has control over that or not... I've worked with some awful APIs that would return crazyness!

Comment: No, I don't. I am not able to create any models.